# decimation of image streams?

Tags: ros, cpu, image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been doing some experimentation with image processing, but I am finding that I am constrained by the available CPU resources.  Is there some method for dropping images from a stream to lower the CPU load?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9874/decimation-of-image-streams?/) by [JonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/317/jonw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 586 on 2011-05-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you just want to drop frames, [throttle](http://www.ros.org/wiki/topic_tools/throttle) in the [topic tools](http://www.ros.org/wiki/topic_tools) should do what you want.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/317/jonw/) on 2011-05-10**:
exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!